# Scala-Making a map from two lists

Tags: scala, list

I have two lists like

```
val lst1 = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
val lst2 = List(12, 13, 12, 15, 16, 21, 23, 30, 32, 13)
```

I would like to make a map like this while the order of values in lst2 does not change in the map:

> Map(1 -> (12, 13, 12, 15, 16), 2 -> (21 , 23), 3 -> (30, 32, 13))

How can I do that?

Comment: The last value is really 13 or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using `zip` and `groupBy`:

```
(lst1 zip lst2).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(
//   2 -> List(21, 23), 1 -> List(12, 13, 12, 15, 16), 3 -> List(30, 32, 13)
// )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am newbie at Scala and has problems with working collections and maps and get stuck with such simple things. Do you have any suggestion to improve my Scala knowledge?

Comment: You might want to pick up a good book like, `Programming in Scala` by Odersky et al.  For instance, in its 2nd/3rd Editions, there is a handful of chapters digging into Scala collections and the related API.  And of course nothing works better than actually writing code when learning a programming language.